# Transformed text as from a specific viewport

Tags: text-manipulation

Is there a possibility to shear (any) LaTeX text or the output of a mathematical formula as it would be obtained as a result from looking at a different angle/viewport?

I do not mean mere rotating of text, that would not be sufficient.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\MyText[2][]{%
  \tikz\node[#1] {#2};%
}

\begin{document}

\MyText[xslant=1.4]{\Huge Some text}
\par\noindent
\MyText[xslant=0.5,yslant=1.5]{\Huge Some text}
\par\noindent
\MyText[xslant=1,yslant=0.5,rotate=-30]{\Huge Some text}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer/solution -I have already considered using a `tikz` based solution, but I am not a frequent user of `tikz` features, so I dropped it due to thinking it would be to difficult. Most probably, there is no 'pure` `LaTeX` solution, without graphical bypassing?